WinRM Listeningon = null, can't change the IP range changing filter in GPO has no effect
I am trying to configure WinRM over HTTPS with a GPO, I have set the filter for the IPv4 range to * and I have also tried using a specific IPv4 range, when I update the GPO there is no change on the listeningon = null it doesn't update to a specific range or IP address, there was a similar questions asked here (WinRM service fails to listen when configured via group policy) I tried changing the registry in the GPO but not sure if I did that correctly or if it's just not working. This is the results when i do the winrm enum winrm/config/listener command when ran on the client.
Listener [Source="GPO"]
    Address = *
    Transport = HTTP
    Port = 5985
    Hostname
    Enabled = true
    URLPrefix = wsman
    CertificateThumbprint
    ListeningOn = null

Listener
    Address = *
    Transport = HTTPS
    Port = 5986
    Hostname = itk
    Enabled = true
    URLPrefix = wsman
    CertificateThumbprint = d3*******************************
    ListeningOn = null

Listener [Source="Compatibility"]
    Address = *
    Transport = HTTPS
    Port = 443
    Hostname = itk
    Enabled = true
    URLPrefix = wsman
    CertificateThumbprint = d3******************************** 
    ListeningOn = null

Something else to note on the server it has a specific listener IP address and I can establish a PSSession from the client to the server but no the other way (from server to client). Any tips or tricks would be greatly appreciated.
